# HaProxy config to redirect request by extracting host details from request

Tags: configuration, haproxy

I wanted a HAProxy config which accepts requests on PORT X and in the backend it send the request to the Host extracted from the request packet.

I have a sample nginx config for same:

```
 server {    
  listen 13080;    
  resolver localhost;

  location / {       
    proxy_set_header Host $host;    
    proxy_pass [http://$host$uri$is_args$args]http://$host$uri$is_args$args;    
    proxy_cache_valid any 1m;    
    proxy_cache_lock on;    
  }    
}
```

In backend how can i extract $host $uri and other details.

Any pointers will help.